# Alternative Specific Variables in R

Tags: r, modeling, multinomial-distribution, mlogit, choice-modeling

I am building a discrete choice model (rail and auto). I have the cost of a trip for each mode (rail versus auto). The utility equations I am building are denoted below:
\begin{align*}
V_\text{auto}
&= \beta_1\cdot\mbox{IVTT}_\text{auto}+ \beta_2\cdot\mbox{OVTT}_\text{auto} \\
V_\text{rail}
&= \beta_0+ \beta_1 \cdot\mbox{IVTT}_\text{rail} + \beta_2 \cdot\mbox{OVTT}_\text{rail}+ \beta_3×\mbox{Cost}_\text{rail}
\end{align*}
The code I have is:

```
data_mlogit<-mlogit.data(newdata,shape="wide",choice="choice",
                         alt.levels=c("auto","rail"),varying=c(6:8,10:12))
model <- mlogit(choice ~ ivtt+ovtt+cost|0|0, data_mlogit)
```

How can I make the code understand to use the cost rail variable only without using the cost auto variable?  I don't want the cost variable (auto) to be part of the utility equation for the auto mode.

Comment: Try setting all auto cost values to NA.

Comment: This might cause difficulties if the OP wanted to use the auto cost variable later. Is there a formula-oriented approach?

Answer (score 2):

I will treat this answer in two parts:

## Why would you want to do this?

To begin with, variables like cost and travel time vary across alternatives, which actually makes them *generic* variables. The multinomial logit model is defined on the difference between two utility functions. Say you have two alternatives (1 and 2), where $x$ is the same in both. If you difference the utility equations, $\alpha_1 + \beta x - [\alpha_2 + \beta x]$ will cancel out $\beta$. So you estimate them as alternative-specific parameters $\alpha_1 + \beta_1 x - [\alpha_2 + \beta_2 x]$, allowing them to be defined.

**But** if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are different, the equation is identifiable with a single $\beta$, 
$\alpha_1 + \beta x_1 - [\alpha_2 + \beta x_2]$

If you estimate this model (I'm only going to use one travel time)

$$ U_{train} = \alpha_{train} + \beta_{tt} (TT_{train})$$
$$ U_{auto} = \alpha_{auto} + \beta_{tt} (TT_{auto})$$

You estimate three parameters ($\alpha_{train}, \alpha_{auto}, \beta_{tt}$). If
you insist on estimating alternative-specific parameters for $\beta_{tt:auto},
\beta_{tt:train}$, you have spent a degree of freedom estimating a parameter
that you don't actually need, which makes your model less efficient, with
knock-on consequences for your hypothesis tests. Not to mention that
cross-elasticities are *lots* easier to calculate with generic coefficients...

You only need alternative specific coefficients if you have variables that
*don't* vary across alternatives, like if you had income, or the distance
between the start and end of the trip.

## Okay, you want to do this anyways, so how do you do it?

There are a couple of ways that I might do this. First I'm going to build
a simple dataset from the Biogeme [swissmetro](http://biogeme.epfl.ch/textFile.php?file=examples/swissmetro/swissmetro.dat) dataset.

```
library(foreign)
swissmetro <- read.delim("~/Downloads/swissmetro.dat")

library(dplyr)
swissmetro <- swissmetro %>% 
  filter(CHOICE %in% c(1, 3)) %>%
  mutate(choice = factor(CHOICE, labels = c("train", "car")),
         tt.train = TRAIN_TT, tt.car = CAR_TT, 
         cost.train = TRAIN_CO, cost.car = CAR_CO) %>%
  select(ID, choice, tt.train, tt.car, cost.train, cost.car)


library(mlogit)
sm <- reshape(swissmetro, varying = 3:6, direction = "long")
sm <- sm %>% 
  mutate(choice = ifelse(choice == time, TRUE, FALSE), alt = time) %>%
  arrange(id) %>% select(-time)
sm.mlogit <- mlogit.data(sm, choice = "choice", id.var = "ID", alt.var = "alt",
                         shape = "long")

head(sm.mlogit)
##         ID choice  tt cost id   alt
## 1.train  1   TRUE 103   36  1 train
## 1.car    1  FALSE  90   65  1   car
## 2.train  7   TRUE  80   42  2 train
## 2.car    7  FALSE  72  140  2   car
## 3.train  8  FALSE 100   22  3 train
## 3.car    8   TRUE  80   24  3   car
```

This replicates (what I think is) your data pretty well, though with only one
travel time
variable. We can **and should** treat both `tt` and `cost` as generic, giving us
the most efficient model,

```
mnl1 <- mlogit(choice ~ tt + cost, data = sm.mlogit)
summary(mnl1)

## 
## Call:
## mlogit(formula = choice ~ tt + cost, data = sm.mlogit, method = "nr", 
##     print.level = 0)
## 
## Frequencies of alternatives:
##   car train 
## 0.684 0.316 
## 
## nr method
## 6 iterations, 0h:0m:0s 
## g'(-H)^-1g = 2.11E-05 
## successive function values within tolerance limits 
## 
## Coefficients :
##                    Estimate Std. Error t-value Pr(>|t|)    
## train:(intercept) -1.33e+00   4.56e-02  -29.16   <2e-16 ***
## tt                -2.57e-04   4.69e-04   -0.55     0.58    
## cost               1.40e-03   5.92e-05   23.71   <2e-16 ***
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
## 
## Log-Likelihood: -2180
## McFadden R^2:  0.225 
## Likelihood ratio test : chisq = 1260 (p.value = <2e-16)
```

### Attempt 1: intercept interaction

My first idea is to interact the generic variables with an intercept, which is
the same as forcing your missing $\beta_{train}$ to equal $0$.

```
sm.mlogit$car <- ifelse(sm.mlogit$alt == "train", 0, 1)
head(sm.mlogit)

##         ID choice  tt cost id   alt car
## 1.train  1   TRUE 103   36  1 train   0
## 1.car    1  FALSE  90   65  1   car   1
## 2.train  7   TRUE  80   42  2 train   0
## 2.car    7  FALSE  72  140  2   car   1
## 3.train  8  FALSE 100   22  3 train   0
## 3.car    8   TRUE  80   24  3   car   1

mnl2 <- mlogit(choice ~ tt + I(cost*car), data = sm.mlogit)
summary(mnl2)

## 
## Call:
## mlogit(formula = choice ~ tt + I(cost * car), data = sm.mlogit, 
##     method = "nr", print.level = 0)
## 
## Frequencies of alternatives:
##   car train 
## 0.684 0.316 
## 
## nr method
## 6 iterations, 0h:0m:0s 
## g'(-H)^-1g = 1.29E-06 
## successive function values within tolerance limits 
## 
## Coefficients :
##                   Estimate Std. Error t-value Pr(>|t|)    
## train:(intercept) 1.01e+00   7.58e-02   13.30   <2e-16 ***
## tt                7.21e-05   4.72e-04    0.15     0.88    
## I(cost * car)     2.84e-02   1.04e-03   27.42   <2e-16 ***
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
## 
## Log-Likelihood: -2230
## McFadden R^2:  0.205 
## Likelihood ratio test : chisq = 1150 (p.value = <2e-16)
```

Comment: @Feras, you may have a perfectly valid reason to do this. If you do, can you share it with me?